# Possible bug in 12.3: NotebookDirectory[] returns not the notebook's own directory, but that of an also opened copy of that notebook

Tags: bugs, notebooks, files-and-directories, version-12.3

**Bug introduced in 12.3, Resolved in 13.1**

---

I am using Windows 10 and found a bug concerning `NotebookDirectory` (and also `NotebookInformation`) in 12.3.
It can be easily reproduced.
Create a new notebook and save it as `notebook1` in a folder, lets say `c:\folder1\notebook1`.
As expected, excecuting `NotebookDirectory[]` gives

```
c:\folder1
```

Now save the notebook and copy it (using the Explorer) into another folder named `c:\folder2`. Rename the copy to `c:\folder2\notebook2.nb` and open it in Mathematica, such that now both notebooks are open. (There is no need to excecute `notebook2.nb`, just open it)
The bug is, that re-excecuting `NotebookDirectory[]` in `notebook1.nb` gives:

```
c:\folder2
```

instead of again `c:\folder1` :-(
This is of course not correct.
I tested this on two machines, and saw the bug on both. Also I assigned different kernels to the notebooks. It does not matter.

Also, after closing and reopening Mathematica: If I open  `notebook1` alone I get the correct notebook directory, if I also open  `notebook2`, I get for `notebook1` the wrong directory.

With *Mathematica* 12.2 I had the problem not. However,I cannot exclude that the bug appeared with the latest Windows update.

Any ideas, what is going on?

Comment: I reproduced this problem (12.3, Windows 10), with an additional problem - if I then close the second file (with or without executing anything), and try `NotebookDirectory[]` in the first file, I get an error: NotebookDirectory::nosv: The notebook NotebookObject[25501141-5cf3-49a4-916b-3b8b6fb97d14] is not saved.

Comment: NotebookInformation[] reveals that both notebooks have identical ExpressionUUIDs. Is this the source of the problem? Or is this expected? I do not know what this ID is used for.

Comment: Now I testet this with 12.2 on the same machine. No problem there. ExpressionUUIDs are identical there, too.

Comment: As my colleagues and me copy notebooks containing NotebookDirectory[] rather commonly, we will go back to 12.2 for now.

Comment: I reported the bug to Wolfram.

Comment: Reproduced with version 12.3.1 on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: I just sent another email to Wolfram support and kindly asked when this issue will be solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an effective solution in this answer:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/257388/82311

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, FrontEnd`FrontEndObjectFormat] = "Legacy"
```

Thanks to josh and Kuba.
In fact, we can find this "NotebookObject and CellObject now use a UUID string instead of specific FrontEndObject values" in incompatible changes of MMA. I think that's the problem.

Comment: I got the same hint from Wolfram support. And some hint that the issue might be solved in 13.1. Let's hope.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't make any comment because of my reputation.

Try with `SetDirectory[NotebookDirector[]]` as first line of you codeflow and then use `Directory[]` instead.

I had a similar problem and It worked for me.

Comment: It doesn't work. You solution relies upun buggy `NotebookDirectory[]`, and hence can't work reliably in principle.