# Changes in the appearance of Mathematica 12.3 when running

Tags: front-end, version-12.3, appearance

I recently installed the 12.3 version of Mathematica and got a bad problem. When I want to run some Mathematica files written in the 12.1 version, the appearance of the Mathematica changes badly so that it makes a lot of trouble. For example, if I run the code

[image]

then it changes to

[image]

Could you please help me with how to figure this problem out and keep the appearance as before?

Comment: I've seen this many times before myself since I installed 12.3. I also have 12.3 and 12.2 and 12.1 on same PC. I could never figure why it happens, i.e why everything become bold and fonts change. I assumed it is due to sharing of files somewhere between different versions. I am on windows 10. I wonder if other see the same thing on the mac.

Comment: Yeah this has been driving me nuts.  If you copy and paste one of these corrupted cells over itself, that repairs it.

Comment: @Nasser Yes, happens randomly on MacOS as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had similar problems when I instaled 12.3:  cells in my notebook would suddenly change to a poorly-readable font which looks like above.  Wolfram support suggested running the following command once as a "patch" until 13 is available:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, FrontEnd`FrontEndObjectFormat] = "Legacy"
```

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: Does "run once" mean once in a session, or once for all the time?

Comment: @Ruslan I have not tested the above, but I am sure it must mean for all time. The command above must update the settings in option inspector and they are saved on disk.

Comment: Yes, execute it once to change the preference for this setting permanently.  Remember to do it again if you reset the preferences.