# The font of my whole document changed after adding a section title

Tags: style, fonts, headers-footers

All my input textn ow looks like this:

[image]

Very unreadable in this font. How to reset it back to normal?

Comment: Try to close the notebook and open it again.

Comment: @user293787 it worked, thank you. But what causes stuff like that to happen? Happens quite often.

Comment: I had a similar problem in ver 12.  See this link for permanent fix:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257386/changes-in-the-appearance-of-mathematica-12-3-when-running/257388#257388